# Why is my Tkinter button not executing my function?

Tags: python, tkinter, random, tkinter-button

```
from tkinter import *
import random
from collections import Counter

root = Tk()
root.title("Random")
root.geometry("600x400")
root.resizable(False, False)


def open_saw():
    saw_wn = Tk()
    saw_wn.title("Random App - Spin a Wheel")
    saw_wn.geometry("600x400")
    saw_wn.resizable(False, False)

    saw_wn.mainloop()


def open_coin():
    c_wn = Tk()
    c_wn.title("Random App - Flip a Coin")
    c_wn.geometry("600x400")
    c_wn.resizable(False, False)

    Label(c_wn, text="                                                                                ").grid(row=0,
                                                                                                              column=0)
    Label(c_wn, text="Flip the coin below!", font=("Yu Gothic UI", 12)).grid(row=0, column=1)

    Label(c_wn, text='                    ').grid(row=1, column=1)

    coin_values = ["Heads", "Tails"]
    coin_face = random.choice(coin_values)

    def flip():
        if coin_face == "Heads":
            Label(c_wn, text="Coin: Heads").place(anchor='s')
        else:
            Label(c_wn, text="Coin: Tails").place(anchor='s')
    coin = Button(c_wn, text='coin', padx=100, pady=90, command=flip)
    coin.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER)

    c_wn.mainloop()


def open_average():
    avg_wn = Tk()
    avg_wn.title("Random App - Averages")
    avg_wn.geometry("840x300")

    Label(avg_wn, text="              ").grid(row=0, column=0)
    avg_instruct = Label(avg_wn, text="Enter your values below to get the averages in mean, median, and mode(put a "
                                      "space between commas")
    avg_instruct.config(font=("Yu Gothic UI", 10))
    avg_instruct.grid(row=0, column=1)

    Label(avg_wn, text="                                     ").grid(row=1, column=0)
    entry = Entry(avg_wn)
    entry.grid(row=2, column=1)

    def calculate():
        list_data = entry.get().split(', ')
        list_data = [float(i) for i in list_data]
        mean = sum(list_data) / len(list_data)
        Label(avg_wn, text='Mean').grid(row=5, column=0)
        Label(avg_wn, text=str(mean)).grid(row=6, column=0)

        list_data_len = len(list_data)
        list_data.sort()

        if list_data_len % 2 == 0:
            median1 = list_data[list_data_len // 2]
            median2 = list_data[list_data_len // 2 - 1]
            median = (median1 + median2) / 2
        else:
            median = list_data[list_data_len // 2]
        Label(avg_wn, text='Median: ' + str(median)).grid(row=5, column=1)
        Label(avg_wn, text=median).grid(row=6, column=1)
        list_data_for_mode = Counter(list_data)
        get_mode = dict(list_data_for_mode)
        mode = [k for k, v in get_mode.items() if v == max(list(list_data_for_mode.values()))]

        if len(mode) == list_data_len:
            get_mode = ["No mode found"]
        else:
            get_mode = [str(i) for i in mode]

        Label(avg_wn, text="Mode: ").grid(row=5, column=2)
        Label(avg_wn, text=get_mode[0]).grid(row=6, column=2)

    Label(avg_wn, text="                                     ").grid(row=3, column=0)

    Button(avg_wn, text='Enter', command=calculate).grid(row=4, column=1)


Label(root, text="                                                          ").grid(row=0, column=0)

title = Label(root, text="Welcome to Random")
title.config(font=("Yu Gothic UI", 24))
title.grid(row=0, column=1)

button1 = Button(root, text="             Spin a wheel             ", padx=80, pady=25, command=open_saw)
button1.place(x=2.25, y=100)

button2 = Button(root, text="Calculate mean, mode, median, and range", padx=20, pady=25, command=open_average)
button2.place(x=325, y=100)

button3 = Button(root, text="Flip a Coin", padx=125, pady=25, command=open_coin)
button3.place(x=2.25, y=200)

button4 = Button(root, text="Generate a number", padx=82, pady=25)
button4.place(x=325, y=200)

root.mainloop()
```

I want the function to display heads or tails(randomly). Instead, the function displays nothing and ignores the function. I have also tried printing the value instead of displaying it on tkinter, but it only shows heads and not tails. If any additional details are needed to solve my issue please comment and I will provide additional details.

Comment: What function is that?

Comment: what do you mean? Sorry for the bad structure of the code but can your clarify more on your question

Comment: It is because you use `anchor='s'` for the label inside nested function `flip()`, so it is put outside the window.  Try `anchor='nw'` and you will see the label at the top-left corner.  Better specify `x` and `y` option in `.place(...)`.

Comment: I meant what function is not being executed by the button (whichever one that is).

Comment: oh the flip() one but its ok now i got the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the function `open_coin`, when the button `coin` is clicked, you are creating the `label` but not specifying the x and y coordinates in `place` , and that too creating everytime the button is pressed. So, create a label to display the result and keep changing its text using `config`.

And the `random` function is called only once, so keep it inside the `flip` function to call everytime in order to get a new random coin value.

```
    .
    .
    CoinLabel = Label(c_wn, text="")  #will be used to display the result
    CoinLabel.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.2, anchor='s')
    
    def flip():
        coin_values = ["Heads", "Tails"]
        coin_face = random.choice(coin_values)
        print(coin_face)
        if coin_face == "Heads":
            CoinLabel.config(text="Coin: Heads")
        else:
            CoinLabel.config(text="Coin: Tails")
    coin = Button(c_wn, text='coin', padx=100, pady=90, command=flip)
    coin.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER)
    .
    .
```